# Finding former bot edits for a Wikipedia page using PyWikiBot

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikimedia, pywikibot

I have currently written this block of code in which the correct number of bots is returned, but upon checking with the https://xtools.wmcloud.org/articleinfo/en.wikipedia.org/Planet_of_the_Apes?botlimit=100#auto-edits page. I can see the bots with '(Former Bot)' after their name are not getting included in the final number. Is there a way to check for these in a general case so the code can also be used on other articles?

I was expecting to get a total of 31 users and actually got 24.

```
 site = pywikibot.Site("en", "wikipedia")
 page = pywikibot.Page(site, 'Planet_of_the_Apes')

 revisions_initial = page.revisions()
 revisions = list(revisions_initial)

 bot_contributors_list = []
    bot_edits = 0

    for Revision in revisions:
        if Revision.anon == False:
            user_check = Revision.user.replace(" ", "_")
            response = requests.get(
            'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.phpaction=query&list=users&ususers=' + user_check +                                  '&usprop=groups&format=json').text
            response_info = json.loads(response)

            if 'bot' in response_info['query']['users'][0]['groups']:
                bot_contributors_list.append(user_check)
                bot_edits = bot_edits + 1

    bot_contributors_set = set(bot_contributors_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The API itself hasn't bot flag filter, (not mention in https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions, in contrast to minor flag) so I think it's impossible.

But, another thing, your code can be two lines instead:

```py
bots = site.allusers(group="bot")
page.revision_count(contributors=bots)
```